# CSS better fit child div within its parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a navigation menu and its corresponding content, I'm using bootstrap.

EDIT as per comment (thank you for pointing that out):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav id="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"></div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul id="main-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="item-1"><a href="#">MENU ENTRY 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="navigation-content" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navigation-content-subsection" id="item-1">
          <div class="something"><p>content for MENU ENTRY 1 goes here.</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Relevant SCSS is:

```
$main-background: #e74c3c;
$menu-background: #ecf0f1;

body {
  background: $main-background;
}

#navigation-content {
  background: $menu-background;
}
```

As you can see the content of a menu entry is shown (it will be shown upon hover event).
The problem I have is that I want a different color for the content and main navigation, but I can't find a way to hide that bottom black line.
It looks like the `navigation-content-subsection` div is not taking the full height or in other words it doesn't fully fit its parent div.

How can I make it so that it hides that bottom black line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

navbar-fixed-top is causing it.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  border-width: 0px;
}
```

I found this out by looking though the chrome dev tools (inspect) until I saw which element had a border.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution to my problem.